# Grid view with dynamic height using auto layout

Tags: ios, grid, autolayout, interface-builder, view

I'm using auto layout to basically create a table (like in Excel or HTML). There are 3 rows and 3 columns. Every row is a view, and every cell is a view inside that row. Every cell contains two labels: one which is always a single line, and one that can be dynamically sized according to it's content.

The idea is that the entire row expands if one of the labels inside the cells expands. I've attached an example to illustrate the way I've layed out my views.

[image: Grid example]

I've constrained all the cells to the top/bottom of their row. The labels have constraints to the sides of their cells. The labels have their number of lines set to 0. The result is this:

[image: Simulator]

Almost what I want. Except the top of the labels aren't aligned. I've played around with the priorities a bit: setting the cells' content hugging priority to 1000, making the bottom space constraint of the labels ">= 0". That doesn't seem to help or generate errors.

Can this be achieved by auto layout? Or should I be using something like a CollectionView?

Comment: Information on constraint is not sufficient to deduce the problem but by looking at the second image i can guess that your top label height is dominating over the height of lower label when the text is less. Apply some background colour to both labels and see if that's true. If that is the case then it means the height is flexible for top label and you need to keep that constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering: I fixed this issue by using nested UIStackViews.

A vertical stackview to hold the rows, the rows are horizontal stackviews, and the cells are vertical stackviews that hold the two labels.

To make the UIStackViews work with the dynamic label height you have to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth (I think this is a bug). I created a UILabel subclass for this:

```
class FixedLabel: UILabel {
    // This is required for iOS 9, to make dynamic labels resize properly

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.width - 1
    }
}
```